# Local file representation of QML's url type

Tags: qml

I want to display the path of a url (QML's url type). Doing that using `toString()` gives me a path with a `file:///` prefix.
Is there a function similar to QUrl's `toLocalFile()` so that I don't need to write one with a regex and platform distinction myself?

Example:

```
property url foo: some_variable_that_links_to_a_QUrl_in_C++
...
Text {
  text: foo
}
```

This shows `file:///my/path/to/happiness/`

But I would like `/my/path/to/happiness/`

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you need the URL in that format? You could just remove the first 7 or so characters in JavaScript. :p

Comment: I need it in that format to display it in the GUI, so it should look nice. ;)
Because on Windows I have to remove `file:///`(3 slashes), whereas on Mac it's only two of them, because I want to keep the leading slash on OSX. Would've been nice to have something similar to `toLocalFile()` of QUrl.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no public QML API for this. You'll have to expose the local file path to QML from C++. You should create a suggestion on the [bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa) though; it seems like a useful thing to have.